# Using a boot to vhd file as a virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vhd, windows-server-2008-r2, boot

I have two boot to vhd files, one for win2k8 and one for win7 ultimate.

If I boot into the win2k8, can I start the win7 vhd as a virtual machine using the windows server 2008 hyper-v tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with Windows Server 2008 built-in virtualization, but I think that it will not work, simply because, on installing Windows, it will customize several files to suit the hardware. In a virtual machine, most of the devices are emulated, and so are different from the host machine's devices. There you have your (theoretical) problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can native boot a vhd file on w2k8r2 and add the hyper-v role, but you can't run a w2k8 or w2k8r2 as a guest and add the hyper-v role to the guests.  The answer to your question is yes!

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to install the Hyper-V role if the Win2k8 is running in a virtual environment. Depending on what OS your running on your Host machine you can boot both vhd’s. Example: if your running a Windows OS as a host – you can use Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 to create a virtual machine. If you have Windows 7 you can use Windows Virtual PC. You can also use Virtual box to load a vhd if your on any other platform.

If you have a computer that supports 64bit OS and has the V-Tech enabled in the BIOS you can install a Windows Server 08 or 08R2 on it and add the Hyper –V role. If the VHD files were created with Hyper-V then you’ll be okay but if they were created with any other Virtual technology make sure to remove the Integrated add-on’s (VM Tools).